# Ejecutar función desde el ámbito de Nodejs pero declarada dentro de socket.io

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Mi pregunta es muy fácil (aunque el título no lo parezca). Si yo declaro una función dentro de socket.io, quisiera ejecutarla desde fuera del contexto de socket.io, así:

```
Ejecutar("Este es mi dato");

io.on("connection", function(socket){
   function Ejecutar(dato){
     socket.emit("mi evento", { "dato": dato});
   }
}
```

Evidentemente, Ejecutar() corre cuando aún socket.io no ha entrado en acción, por eso no la reconoce y me bota el error "undefined". Necesito ejecutarlo así porque estoy recibiendo eventos de un Asterisk y cada vez que reciba data de un evento quisiera enviarlo por socket.io al cliente. Espero sus comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarala asi

```
function Ejecutar(data){
    //Codigo funcion

}
io.on('connection', function(socket)){
   //Suponiendo que hay un dato mas arriba...asi estaba en su ejemplo
   Ejecutar(dato);
}
//Suponiendo que hay un dato mas arriba...asi estaba en su ejemplo
Ejecutar(dato);
```

O en su defecto asi si definitivamente se necesita declarar la funcion dentro de socket IO

```
var funcion = null;

io.on('connection', function(socket)){
   //Si en su defecto se necesita que se declare dentro de socket io
  funcion =  function Ejecutar(data){
   //Codigo funcion

 }

}
//Validar antes por si el llamado se da antes que se conecte socket io
if(funcion){
   funcion(dato);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, realmente la segunda opción me ha servido.